# Is it possible to reduce the amount of points of polygons from overpass-turbo export?

Tags: overpass-api

I have this query:

```
[out:json][timeout:25];
{{geocodeArea:Latvia}}->.searchArea;
// gather results
(
  // query part for: “admin_level=6”
  relation["admin_level"="6"](area.searchArea);
);
// print results
out meta;
way(r);
out body;
>;
out skel qt;
```

http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/cds

Size of output file is near 20mb. I want to reduce size by reducing the amount of points. Is it possible to achieve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simplified output for e.g. rendering purposes has been proposed in the [following GitHub ticket](https://github.com/drolbr/Overpass-API/issues/171). However, as the feature hasn't been implemented yet, there's nothing you can do from within Overpass API to significantly reduce the data volume at this time.

Alternative approach: use QGIS + QuickOSM to download / simplify the data and store it as shapefile for further processing.

Answer (score -1):

If you're not familiar with GIS software, this very simple online tool might be useful four you: http://www.mapshaper.org/
It's built just for this task. Didn't really reduce the file size in my use case though.